# "First Posts" review queue shows as in the "danger zone" even when it is empty

Tags: bug, status-declined

**EDIT:** Not a bug; see [[this answer below]](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/a/63/38).

---

The "First Posts" review queue has a red dot (indicating [danger zone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly)) even when it is empty:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes a while for the red dot to disappear. This can happen when very recently before you click on the review queues, all the first posts were reviewed.

Comment: How long is a while? I feel like it's been consistently red since it first turned red, in my queue.

Comment: Until there are less than $n$ posts, where $n$ is unknown to us. Also, it takes more than one person to review a first post, hence why in the [Review Stats](https://or.stackexchange.com/review), there are still 3 posts, which can cause the red dot to appear.

Comment: Aha. That totally makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Should I just delete this question?

Comment: I think so, it is very likely that it has been asked on Meta.SE years ago (and this issue is not specific to this site)

Comment: Hmm, I can't delete it because "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it." And none of the reasons for closing it are appropriate. So I guess I'll just leave it...

Comment: Why not keeping it? Indeed it is not specific to this site but I guess that the OR forum has a large population of new users which are more likely to visit this meta site than other meta sites. I liked reading this post and wouldn't have read it on another meta.